# Is there a way to limit Google Maps Markers on web?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typescript, ionic-framework

I basically have a Ionic app that takes a user click on the map and return it to the user, no problem there. My problem is when the user clicks multiple times in the map, I added the markers to inform the user the location he has chosen and I want it so that each time he clicks on the map the number of markers will stay one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps you are creating a new marker and using `marker.setMap(map);` This creates a new marker and adds it to the current map.

Do not define new marker and just use setPosition instead to change the position of current marker:

```
marker.setPosition(position);
```

where position is the array of {lat,lng} from click position; Do not forget to define the marker as a global variable So you can use it both on creating a map and also to update the position;

```
var marker;
function initMap() {
        //Here you initialize the map and marker then
        marker.setMap(map);
      }
function updateMarkerPosition(lat,lng){
    marker.setPosition({lat:" + lat +",lng:"+ lng+ "});
}
```

Comment: It worked!

`export class className{
    marker: any;
}

ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.initMap();
}

initMap(){
    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map});
}

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', event=>{
         this.updateMarkerPosition(event.latLng(), event.latLng.lng());
}
}

updateMarker Position(lat, lng){
    this.marker.setPosition({
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
})
}`